# Implementing `define_singleton_method` in pure Ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

`define_singleton_method` makes it easy to access outer scope in the defined method body. Something along the lines of:

```
def messenger(text)
  Object.new.tap do |m|
    m.define_singleton_method(:message) { text }
  end
end
```

Is it possible to achieve similar effect without actually calling `define_singleton_method` (and also without evaluating a string)?

Comment: What exactly were you hoping for? Can you provide a use case? What is your issue with `define_singleton_method`?

Comment: I remember implementing this functionality without using it but can't remember how I did it.

Comment: @synapse What do you mean by "(and also without evaluating a string)". Your definition of `:messenger` intends that a string, `text`, will be evaluated, so it looks like there's no escaping string evaluation. Please indicate what your use case is. Please indicate in what context `:messenger` is called.

Comment: Well as with most things in ruby there is generally more than one way to achieve the same result without an understanding of what exactly you are trying to achieve or why this question may fall into the category of too broad. Maybe you care looking for `instance_eval`?

Comment: @progfan I meant without evaluating a string of Ruby code

Comment: @engineersmnky I want to make a function that does exactly what `messenger` function in my example does but doesn't use `define_singleton_method` i.e. I want to write a pure Ruby version of `define_singleton_method` (it's written in C in Ruby standard library)

Comment: here is how `rubinius` implements in pure ruby `def define_singleton_method(*args, &block);
    singleton_class.send(:define_method, *args, &block);
end` additionally `m.instance_eval { define_method(:message) { text } }` would work and a few other solutions as well. That was kind of my point

Comment: thanks, that's the answer I was looking for